# Performing action every few seconds, no matter what happens in running loop

Tags: ruby, loops, delay

I have a little problem. I want to iterate loop every time there is new line from socket, so I use this loop:

```
until @socket.eof? do
  #something
end
```

And I also want to perform one action every 10 seconds, so I did something like this:

```
until @socket.eof? do
  do_something

  if time_last+10 < Time.now 
    time_last = Time.now
    do_something_else
  end 
end
```

And my problem is that, that `do_something_else` action is performed only after there is a new line on socket. There is no problem if there is 100 lines / second. But if there is no new lines, nothing happens.
And if I get this whole `if` outside of `until` loop it woks only once on program start. Can I run two loops at once somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule tasks, the best way is to use a scheduler.

You can do this using OpenWFEru and then:

> scheduler.schedule_every('10s') { do_something }

See more in the link below:
https://www.igvita.com/2007/03/29/scheduling-tasks-in-ruby-rails/

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to block on the socket. In this loop, it tries to read for 0.2 seconds and then checks if a task has to be launched. $guest is an array of sockets.

```
loop do
  if task_time + 0.1 < now = Time.now.to_f
    Task.execute(task_time = now)
  end
  next unless ready = select($guest, nil, nil, 0.2)
  now = Time.now.to_f
  for sock in ready[0]
  // [...]
  end
end
```

This is an extract of some legacy code of mine, but it sure works:

https://github.com/rosedomini/MystMUD/blob/master/MystMUD/myst/myst/mud.rb